# Dynamically display JSON data in data table layout in flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, arraylist, datatable

I am Creating  a Dynamic data table view in flutter , where the column headers and the row values are added dynamically. The data is a Json response,the header is a string array and the data to be displayed in  row is also a string array .The goal is to display the data in the table view without any hardcoded values.
This is how I have tried is to display the data.

```
                     return ListView.builder(
                         shrinkWrap: true,
                         scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                         itemCount: snapshot.data.dataList.length,
                         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                           return SingleChildScrollView(
                             child: DataTable(
                               columns: (snapshot.data.headerList[index] as List).map((item) =>
                               DataColumn(
                                   label:(
                                       List.generate(item.length,(index){
                                         return Text(item[index].toString());
                                       })
                                   )
                               )).toList(),
                               rows: (snapshot.data.dataList[index].dataList as List).map((item) =>
                               
                               DataRow(
                                 
                                   cells:<DataCell>[
                                     DataCell(
                                         List.generate(item.length,(index){
                                           return Text(item[index].toString());
                                         })
                                     )
                                    ])).toList(),
                             ),
```

This is the JSON response

```
 "DayEnd": {
        "ColumnWidths": "40´168´96´96´108´156",
        "Headers": "SL.>´Customer< ´Balance Qty>´Amount>´Oldest / Recent ",
        "FieldSeparator": "´",
        "DataList": [
            {
                "Data": "1. ´ABD ´14 / 14.60´11,090´313 / 313",
                "NextLevelZoomData": [
                    {
                        "Element": "eg7P27fbW/GmCr"
                    },
                    {
                        "Element": "AAA=="
                    }
                ],
                "NextLevelZoomType": 2
            },
            {
                "Data": "2. ´LATA´16´7,921´20 / 9",
                "NextLevelZoomData": [
                    {
                        "Element": "MT63z0m7piukmtJZqdZ"
                    },
                    {
                        "Element": "QT/2zE/AAA="
                    }
                ],
                "NextLevelZoomType": 2
            },
            {
                "Data": "3. ´ANAND´11´915´426 / 426",
                "NextLevelZoomData": [
                    {
                        "Element": "AAA="
                    }
                ],
                "NextLevelZoomType": 2
            },
            {
                "Data": "4. ´Asts´1´1,010´27 / 27",
                "NextLevelZoomData": [
                    {
                        "Element": "w/VbTHwKgQAAA=="
                    }
                ],
                "NextLevelZoomType": 2
            },
            }
```

The above response gives a string data `Headers` which is  separated by a special character "`",the each character has to be displayed in a each column header so  which is converted to an array. Similarly the data as well . The column width that has to be maintained for each data is mentioned in columnWidth
Similarly the alignment of the data like if "SL.>" then ">" it has to be right aligned.

I am not sure if this is the right approach to get it, This gives an error

```
The argument type 'List<Text>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'.
```

Any idea to approach in a better way will be much appreciated.

Comment: please add your json responce if possible

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede added json response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1:

```
[
  {
    "DayEnd": [
      {
        "ColumnWidths": "40´168´96´96´108´156",
        "Headers": "SL.>´Customer< ´Balance Qty>´Amount>´Oldest / Recent ",
        "FieldSeparator": "´",
        "DataList": [
          {
            "Data": "1. ´ABD ´14 / 14.60´11,090´313 / 313",
            "NextLevelZoomData": [
              {
                "Element": "eg7P27fbW/GmCr"
              },
              {
                "Element": "AAA=="
              }
            ],
            "NextLevelZoomType": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Step 2:

```
 class TableModel {
  TableModel(this.headerData, this.rowData);
  List<String> headerData;
  List<List<String>> rowData;

  factory TableModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TableModel(
      json['DayEnd'][0]["Headers"].split('´').toList(),
      buildRowData(json),
    );
  }
}

List<List<String>> buildRowData(Map<String, dynamic> json){
  List<List<String>> rowDataCollection = [];
  json['DayEnd'][0]["DataList"].forEach((rows){
    rowDataCollection.add(rows['Data'].split('´').toList());
  });

  return rowDataCollection;
}
```

Step 3:

```
Future<void> generateList() async {
    String responseBody = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/data.json");
    var list = await json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return await list
        .map<TableModel>((json) => TableModel.fromJson(json))
        .toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('DataTable'),
            ),
            body: FutureBuilder(
              future: generateList(),
              builder: (context, snapShot) {
                if (snapShot.data == null ||
                    snapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ||
                    snapShot.hasError ||
                    snapShot.data.length == 0) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                  );
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: snapShot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        final TableModel table = snapShot.data[index];
                        return SingleChildScrollView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          child: DataTable(
                            columns: table.headerData.map<DataColumn>((e) {
                              var columnName = e;
                              TextAlign align;
                              if (columnName.contains('<')) {
                                align = TextAlign.start;
                                columnName = columnName.replaceAll('<', '');
                              } else if (columnName.contains('>')) {
                                align = TextAlign.end;
                                columnName = columnName.replaceAll('>', '');
                              } else {
                                align = TextAlign.center;
                              }

                              return DataColumn(
                                  label: Text(
                                columnName,
                                textAlign: align,
                              ));
                            }).toList(),
                            rows: table.rowData.map<DataRow>((e) {
                              return DataRow(
                                  cells: e
                                      .map<DataCell>((e) => DataCell(Text(e)))
                                      .toList());
                            }).toList(),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                }
              },
            )));
  }
```

[image: DataTable]

Comment: thankyou for the soultion. It is reallly helpful. With some modifications i was able to achieve the result. But one issue came up is header is getting repeated for all columns . Is there something im going wrong

Comment: Can you please share some more example of your structured dummy json data it will help me to understand.. how to extract the data and which widget will suit for that .

Comment: Hi @Android_id I have modified the step 2. please look into it

Comment: Please share the image  , I will try to sort it out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228133/discussion-between-balasubramani-sundaram-and-android-id).

Answer (score 1):

use createTable() & give it list & the object must have .tojson() method

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// This class takes any list that its elements have .toJson method and return every list element as a table row
class TableController {
  static Widget createTable(List list) {
    List<TableRow> rows = [];
    rows.add(_createTableHeader(list[0].toJson().keys));
    for (var item in list) {
      rows.add(TableRow(
        children: _createTableBody(item.toJson().values),
      ));
    }
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Table(border: TableBorder.all(), children: rows),
    );
  }

  static TableRow _createTableHeader(Iterable<String> keys) {
    List<Widget> elements = [];
    for (String key in keys) {
      elements.add(Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: Text(key.toString(), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
      ));
    }
    return TableRow(
      children: elements,
    );
  }

  static List<Widget> _createTableBody(Iterable values) {
    List<Widget> elements = [];
    for (var value in values) {
      elements.add(Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: Text(value.toString(), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
      ));
    }
    return elements;
  }
}
```

use it like this:

```
class Employee {
      Employee({
        this.id,
        this.name,
        this.email,
      });
    
      int id;
      String name;
      String email;
    
      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
            "id": id,
            "name": name,
            "email": email,
          };
    }
    
    final Employee emp = Employee(id: 1, name: 'name 1');
    final Employee emp1 = Employee(id: 2, name: 'name 2');
    final Employee emp2 = Employee(id: 3, name: 'name 3');
    final Employee emp3 = Employee(id: 4, name: 'name 4');
    final List<Employee> emps = [emp, emp2, emp1];

class TablePage extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(child: TableController.createTable(emps)),
        );
      }
    }
```

output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set List to properties that have Widget types: label in DataColumn, and child in DataCell. List is not subtype of Widget. Probably you need ListView here.