# How to change width of datacells dynamically in flutter DataTable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have found in this link a way to place data from JSON dynamically to `DataTable()` widget:

[Dynamically display JSON data in data table layout in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856234/dynamically-display-json-data-in-data-table-layout-in-flutter)

In that post he has `ColumnWidths` in the json but he doesn't show how he changes width of the individual datacell columns.

I have used that example for myself as well and I wonder how I can use the column widths from json as well to change width of individual data cells?

This is the json I am using:

```
[
  {
    "table-data": [
      {
        "table-label-data": "SL.´Customer´Balance Qty´Amount´Oldest / Recent ",
        "table-row-list": [
          {
            "table-row-data": "1. ´ABD ´14 / 14.60´11,090´313 / 313"
          },
          {
            "table-row-data": "1. ´ABD ´14 / 14.60´11,090´313 / 313"
          }
        ],
        "table-cell-widths": "40´168´96´96´108"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is the model I am using:

```
import 'dart:ui';

class TableModel {
  TableModel(this.labelData, this.rowData);
  List<String> labelData;
  List<List<String>> rowData;

  factory TableModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TableModel(
      json['table-data'][0]["table-label-data"].split('´').toList(),
      buildRowData(json),
    );
  }
}

List<List<String>> buildRowData(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  List<List<String>> rowDataCollection = [];
  json['table-data'][0]["table-row-list"].forEach((rows) {
    rowDataCollection.add(rows['table-row-data'].split('´').toList());
  });

  return rowDataCollection;
}
```

For the view as you can see i use a variable `width` inside `SizedBox` widget to change width, but it is now changing all widths but i want to change individual data cell widths based on json.

This is the view:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:test_project/controllers/getters/get_test.dart';

import '../models/table_model.dart';
import '../models/test_model.dart';

class AppView2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppView2({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppViewState createState() => _AppViewState();
}

class _AppViewState extends State<AppView2> {
  Future<void> generateList() async {
    String responseBody =
        await rootBundle.loadString("assets/tableJsonData.json");
    var list = await json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return await list
        .map<TableModel>((json) => TableModel.fromJson(json))
        .toList();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    generateList();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('DataTable'),
            ),
            body: FutureBuilder(
              future: generateList(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapShot) {
                if (snapShot.data == null ||
                    snapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ||
                    snapShot.hasError ||
                    snapShot.data.length == 0) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                  );
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: snapShot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        final TableModel table = snapShot.data[index];
                        return SingleChildScrollView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          child: DataTable(
                            columns: table.labelData.map<DataColumn>((e) {
                              var columnName = e;

                              return DataColumn(
                                  label: Text(
                                columnName,
                              ));
                            }).toList(),
                            rows: table.rowData.map<DataRow>((e) {
                              return DataRow(
                                  cells: e.map<DataCell>((e) {
                                var dataCell = e;
                                dynamic width;

                                return DataCell(SizedBox(
                                  width: width,
                                  child: Text(
                                    dataCell,
                                  ),
                                ));
                              }).toList());
                            }).toList(),
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                }
              },
            )));
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution here?